# Giving a variable a specific different name based on class id

Tags: javascript

I have a default variable which comes from somewhere that I can't change it.

I can take the value of this variable using this:

```
var.name = {{var1}}
```

for example this variable could have the valua name: "test"

I would like to change this variable if there is a specific class in the page code something like the following:

```
<p class="pclass"></p>
```

and the first variable I mentioned early take a different name. If there isn't this class the first value have the initial change.

I thoug to use something like this

```
value = var.name
if ( value =="test" && document.getElementsByClassName("pclass") )
{
var.name = pclass
}else{
return var.name
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to search your document to see if the pclass exists?
You can do a document.getElementsByClassName("pclass"), to see if it exists

Comment: Generally I though to check two conditions in order to see if I could change the variable but as you can see my code is half because I am newbee in this.

Comment: ah I see, hold on, writing it.

Comment: @Ted I made a simple update based on your recommendation any help for improvements?

Comment: I've added a solution that I think it will fit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to check the document if the class exists in any element, and if it does, change the variables name. Here goes:

```
// Find all elements with that className
var elementsFound = document.getElementsByClassName("pClass");

// Check if the length of elementsFound is bigger than 0, if it is, it means there is more than 0 elements with that class, so the class exists somewhere
if (elementsFound.length > 0) {
    var.name = "pClass";
}
```

And that's it. There is not need for "else" because the original variable hasn't been changed unless that condition verifies. You can of course add more validation's (like var.name == teste, etc) to that.

And you can also convert it into an 1 line only:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("pClass").length > 0) 
    var.name = "pClass";
```

**Edit**

If you want two validations (not controls), your logic was correct, but the code wasn't in only a small part:

```
if (var.name == "test" && ..... )
```

You need to put " around the name you want to compare, the string. Besides that, it should work.

Comment: If I want to use two controls I should write this ' if (var.name == teste && document.getElementsByClassName("pClass").length > 0)?

Comment: The logic is correct, the code is a tiny wrong. Look in my original answer where I edited.